# TensorFlow GPU memory

Tags: tensorflow, memory-management, gpu

I have a very large deep neural network. when I try to run it on GPU I get "OOM when allocating". but when I mask the GPU and run on CPU it works (about 100x slower when comparing small model).

My question is if there is any mechanism in tenosrflow that would enable me to run the model on GPU. I assume the CPU uses virtual memory so it can allocates as much as he likes and move between cache/RAM/Disk (thrashing).

is there something similiar on Tensorflow with GPU? that would help me even if it will be 10x slower than regular GPU run

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GPU memory is currently not extensible  (Till something like [PASCAL](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/beyond-gpu-memory-limits-unified-memory-pascal/) is available)